# Hide lines in .bash_profile

Tags: linux

is there any way to hide lines in `.bash_profile`, so if someone opens the file, cannot see the line? The reason is I need to set a password for database as a variable, and just putting the plain password does not work for me. By the way, someone recommended base64 encoding, which is useless in this case

Comment: It's a bad idea indeed. The password stored this way isn't secure by definition.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, no there is no way to hide lines of a text file like `.bash_profile`.

However, there might be other solutions, such as using `ssh-agent` if your use case involves `ssh`.